# UIDatePicker with year '----'

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

[rephrase]

Hi
 
my original question was not clear enough - let me rephrase.
When entering anniversary at Contact app of iOS, I see the year has '----' (see the picture).
I thought it's UIDatepicker but couldn't find how to.. 
(I checked the developer documentation but no way).
please help me to make it! Thanks!

[original question]
I'm trying to figure out how 'year' of this UIDatePicker set '----' for Anniversary - it's from iOS contact app.

I checked the developer [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker) for UIDatePicker but couldn't find anything about it.
Anyone knows?

[iOS Contact app - UIDatepicker for Anniversary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BEf7.jpg)

Comment: Are you asking how to show a date picker without a year component or how to show a date picker where the year components show "----" for one of its values?

Comment: Please re-phrase your question. Please specify what actually you are looking for

Comment: I might be wrong, but do you really want the year or not. Unable to understand here

Comment: This is not a UIDatePicker. This is a UIPickerView

Comment: @LeoDabus - oh! let me check UIPickerView!!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Leo! 
It's really shameful that I didn't know about UIpickerview..
I could create UIPickerView with year '----'.

[UIPickerview with year ----](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnFkq.png)

```
let monthArray = [......]
let dayArray = [......]
let yearArray = ["2016", "2017", "2018", "----", "2019", "2020", "2021"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    switch component {
    case 0:
        return self.monthArray.count
    case 1:
        return self.dayArray.count
    case 2:
        return self.yearArray.count
    default:
        print ("do nothing")
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    switch component {
    case 0:
        return monthArray[row]
    case 1:
        return dayArray[row]
    case 2:
        return yearArray[row]
    default:
        print ("do nothing")
    }
    return nil
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let monthSelected = self.monthArray[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    let daySelected = self.dayArray[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
    let yearSelected = self.yearArray[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)]

    self.daySelectedLabel.text = monthSelected + " " + daySelected + ", " + yearSelected
}
```